# Querying Quickbooks from an ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, quickbooks

I'm trying to enable a web application I've written in ASP.NET MVC2 to be able to send and receive data to and from Quickbooks *on-demand*, without a delay/intermediate database/sync operation. (Please take this as an assumption; I understand that it would be a better idea to use the Web Connector and sync every X units of time, but that is outside of the framework of discussion for this question)

It seems that the only way to do this is to write a regular application (it apparently will not work at all from a service), and then have the webapp communicate with that application and send and recieve data through that application.

So my question is **what is the ideal way of setting up an intermediate application that will communicate with the web app?**

Should I write a regular console application and get data from standard output? Or are there better ways of accomplishing the same goal?

Comment: why wouldn't it work as a service? What kind of service was this? WCF?

Comment: Apparently an inherent limitation of QuickBooks SDK. Writing the QBSDK equivalent of "Hello World" works fine as a console app, but that same exact code in a service throws an exception "Could not start Quickbooks."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickBooks exposes it's API through a COM interface and there are some limitations in how that can be used. An intermediate application that acts as an relay is an appropriate solution.

I would recommend building or using an application that listens over HTTP and proxies requests and responses to QuickBooks. In fact we use exactly the same approach in our product - RSSBus QuickBooks ADO.NET provider. Here are more details of what we do it in our product: http://rssbus.com/kb/help/RQR1-A/pg_qbconnector.rst

Comment: Yep, I found your product a few days ago and now it's the one that I'm using. It's the best solution out there, and certainly better than writing your own web service.